# GridView a BD SQL Server

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, aspx

Buen día.

Tengo un proyecto para vaciar los datos de un GridView que se agregaron mediante un archivo excel, el que solo cuenta con una columna. Mi idea es con un select seleccionar todos los datos del gridview y con un ciclo irlo guardando en una tabla en sql, pero no se como referirme al gridview para el select, mi codigo hasta ahora es el siguiente.

```
    Dim cn7 As New SqlConnection
    cn7.ConnectionString = cadenaConexion
    Dim cmd7 As New SqlCommand()
    cmd7.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM (GridView1)"
    cmd7.Connection = cn7
    cn7.Open()
    Dim dr1 As SqlDataReader
    dr1 = cmd7.ExecuteReader
    Dim encontro = False
    Label3.Text = dr1("Num_Inventario").ToString.Trim
    While dr1.Read
        encontro = True
        Dim cn8 As New SqlConnection
        cn8.ConnectionString = cadenaConexion
        Dim cmd8 As New SqlCommand()
        cmd8.CommandText = "INSERT INTO bienes_temporal(Num_Inventario) VALUES ('" & dr1("Num_Inventario") & "')"
        cmd8.Connection = cn8
        cn8.Open()
        cmd8.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End While
```

¿Alguien sabe o tiene la solución?

Answer (score 0):

Opté por hacerlo de la siguiente manera y si funcionó.

```
Dim cn9 As New SqlConnection
        cn9.ConnectionString = cadenaConexion
        Dim cmd9 As New SqlCommand()
        For Each gvrow In GridView1.Rows
            cmd9.CommandText = "INSERT INTO bienes_temporal(Num_Inventario) VALUES ('" & gvrow.Cells(0).Text & "')"
            cmd9.Connection = cn9
            cn9.Open()
            cmd9.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn9.Close()
        Next
        Label3.Text = "Se guardó correctamente"
```

Comment: Aqui el detalle es que  por cada recorrido en tu ciclo, estas haciendo una llamada a la base de datos, lo cual puede dejar tu informacion corrupta ante un error, sin mencionar la caida en el desempeño de tu aplicacion. Yo usaria el mismo ciclo pero lo iria guardando en un datatable, para que al final haga una sola insercion (con todos los registros) mediante una tabla defina por el usuario (tabla de paso) en sql.

Answer (score 0):

adicionalmente Puedes implementar un manejo de Excepciones en caso de que pasara algo al momento de ejecutar el "insert" de esa manera tu aplicación no se va a caer por completo

```
    Dim cn9 As New SqlConnection
    cn9.ConnectionString = cadenaConexion
    Dim cmd9 As New SqlCommand()
    For Each gvrow In GridView1.Rows
        cmd9.CommandText = "INSERT INTO bienes_temporal(Num_Inventario) VALUES ('" & gvrow.Cells(0).Text & "')"
        cmd9.Connection = cn9
        cn9.Open()
        Try
           cmd9.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex as Exception
           Label3.Text = "error :" & ex.message
        End Try            
        cn9.Close()
    Next
    Label3.Text = "Se guardó correctamente"
```